# Can lightning component be used in desktop application?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

I am developing a lightning component, I am adding it in a lightning app builder and using it, but how can i use the same lightning component in desktop.
Also, should i use lightning design system or bootstrap while building responsive lightning component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your component to be available for use in Lightning pages on the platform, just as with Salesforce1, it needs to have the following line added to it:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
```

To use it on a visualforce page, also add the following:

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp"> 
    <aura:dependency resource="ui:button"/>
</aura:application>
```

If you want to add it to a community page, you need to add this line:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:layout" access="global">
```

If you want to use it with the desktop, the LDS will be the most compatible to use.

For more, see the [Lightning Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_framework.htm) and the [Lightning FAQ](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_FAQ).

Comment: Can i use bootstrap and LDS together. If not, which one to use as i want my component to be mobile as well as desktop ready.

Comment: You can use either one of them. Both work well for mobiles. Using both may result in CSS conflicts.

Comment: It's possible to use bootstrap. SF recommends you use LDS. You'll find a number of posts in the forum on issues people have had using bootstrap. I recommend you search for them and read them.

Comment: Ok..Thnx a lot guys.